# How to Load only current pages of Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have involved with Fragments page-loads problem. I create a 10-Fragments and identify the current Fragment by onPageChanged(). I am updating the contents of each Fragment during swipe.
but if i am doing to update one Fragment and show values. it is displaying wrong index value at wrong pages.

```
I noted, Fragment is loading previous and next pages also. so if i display current fragment values by changing the resources, it changes previous and next resources but not current.
```

example:-  if i am in pageno-3, if display the update values of pageno-3 at pageno-4 , it happens during left to right swipe

but i will do right to left swipe, it display the update values of pageno-3 at pageno-2

Comment: I didn't get your question. Can you please use the English language in such a way that one can understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set control in visiblity like this:

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
if((visible )  )
{
 //set your adapter or listview 
}

}
```

if you set this in your 2 and 4 , when you come 3. page the other ones does not triggered.

Comment: Thx for that, I am confuse where should i need to use it either activity class or Fragment class?

Comment: in fragment class you can use it

Comment: if visible true:-  I am trying to updating values by write code inside setMenuVisibility().  but i am getting null pointer exception due to "SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("

Comment: please what should i need to do inside setMenuVisibility() so that my left and right fragment will not be trigged

Comment: in your right and left fragment I think there is some code for load listviw or something. YOu can move them to setmenuvisibility method.

Comment: currently working. if first time Fragment is loaded. it used if not null for all values and do not do any thing. after that working

Answer (score 1):

I think you should extend the Fragment class. Inside the new class define a method

```
public void refresh(NewValuesObject obj){
    ... do something with the new values

};
```

Inside your onPageChanged callback call this method with the desired params.
You may want to save your fragment instances and do the updates (call refresh) for the fragment at the previous or next index.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for that, I used but gave me null pointer exception at **   SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(**